# ¿Cómo establecer la comunicación entre un servlet y un .html?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlets

estoy aprendiendo servlets y no logro entender por qué al ejecutarlo me aparece el error HTTP 404,según yo tengo la estructura correcta, la estructura de mi proyecto es ésta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código del servlet es éste:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código html es éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el web.xml es :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. El código se comparte siempre como texto para las preguntas en SO. Por otra parte, ¿cuál petición te da 404?

Comment: @Alfabravo  pues es que al correr el puro servlet indica el 404, se sé si esté mal mi web.xml

Answer (score 0):

en el servlet no estas utilizando el método correcto, para recibir parámetros del formulario mediante post sería el método

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

en vez del método "processRequest" que estas usando.

Saludos.